# Pandas: Change values chosen by boolean indexing in a column without getting a warning

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, indexing, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe, I want to change only those values of a column where another column fulfills a certain condition. I'm trying to do this with `iloc` at the moment and it either does not work or I'm getting that annoying warning:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
DF = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1],'B':['a','a','b','c','x','t','i','x','b']})
```

Doing one of those

```
DF['B'].iloc[:][DF['A'] == 1] = 'X'

DF.iloc[:]['B'][DF['A'] == 1] = 'Y'
```

works, but leads to the warning above.

This one also gives a warning, but does not work:

```
DF.iloc[:][DF['A'] == 1]['B'] = 'Z'
```

I'm really confused about how to do boolean indexing using `loc`, `iloc`, and `ix` right, that is, how to provide row index, column index, AND boolean index in the right order and with the correct syntax.

Can someone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are chaining you're selectors, leading to the warning.  Consolidate the selection into one.
Use `loc` instead

```
DF.loc[DF['A'] == 1, 'B'] = 'X'
DF
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
import pandas as pd
DF = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1],'B':['a','a','b','c','x','t','i','x','b']})


DF.ix[DF['A'] == 1, 'B'] = 'X'
print (DF)

0  1  X
1  1  X
2  2  b
3  1  X
4  2  x
5  2  t
6  1  X
7  2  x
8  1  X
```

Another solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
DF.B = DF.B.mask(DF['A'] == 1, 'X')
print (DF)
   A  B
0  1  X
1  1  X
2  2  b
3  1  X
4  2  x
5  2  t
6  1  X
7  2  x
8  1  X
```

Nice article about [`SettingWithCopy` by Tom Augspurger](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1.html).

Comment: Thanks for the article, sadly none of the links in it work, they all 404.

Comment: Interesting, for me it works very nice. Maybe `firewall` problem?

Comment: This links are from official [pandas documentation - Modern pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html)

Comment: Found the problem. Everything works if I click on a subpage first, i.e. "Modern Pandas (Part 1)" and from there on one of the list items. Directly clicking on list items on the overview page does not work because their link adresses are different, they have an additional `/author/` in the link which apparently is wrong.

Comment: Interesting, i try change link in answer to `http://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1.html`, now it works?

Comment: Since `ix` is deprecated and this question is pretty popular, do you want to edit your question to reflect the current state of things?